# Dart private property

Tags: dart, private-members

Some said that private properties can be used to change class definition without changing existing codes depending on the class before.

For example;

```dart
main() {
  var p1 = new Project();
  p1.name = 'Breeding';
  p1.description = 'Managing the breeding of animals';
  print('$p1');
  // prints: Project name: Breeding - Managing the breeding of animals
}

class Project {
  String name, description;

  toString() => 'Project name: $name - $description';
}
```

Now, class Project is changed as below using private variables.

```dart
main() {
  var p1 = new Project();
  p1.name = 'Breeding';
  p1.description = 'Managing the breeding of animals';
  print('$p1');
  // prints: Project name: BREEDING - Managing the breeding of animals
  var p2 = new Project();
  p2.name = 'Project Breeding of all kinds of animals';
  print("We don't get here anymore because of the exception!");
}

class Project {
  String _name; // private variable
  String description;

  String get name => _name == null ? "" : _name.toUpperCase();
  set name(String prName) {
    if (prName.length > 20)
      throw 'Only 20 characters or less in project name';
    _name = prName;
  }

  toString() => 'Project name: $name - $description';
}
```

What does it mean that;

> (due to the private properties introduced) The code that already existed in main (or in general, the client code that uses this property) does not need to change

The author of the above codes(Learning Dart) said that, due to the newly inserted private property(_name), the existing codes like 'main()' are NOT affected by the change of properties in the Project class.

That's what I can't understand. How newly inserted private properties in existing classes can be a way to keep other codes depending on those classes untouched or safe?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Hi, Günter. I edited the content to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know what your actual question is.

You can use private fields, classes and functions/methods to reorganize (refactor) your code and
as long as the public API is not affected and the users of the library do not depend on the internal behavior of the classes the users should not recognize the change.
Privacy is mostly a communication medium to indicate that some members (public) are intended to be accessed by API users and private members are an implementation detail the API user should not care about.
Don't confuse privacy with security. Reflection usually allows access to private members.

If this is not the answer you were looking for please add a comment or improve your question.

Comment: I think my answer answers your refined question. You can change the internal implementation of the class, split big public or private methods in more smaller ones. If you have a public field you can change it to a public get/setter pair and store the value in a field with a different name. This way you can put additional code into the getter/setter and the users of the class don't need to be aware of the change. You can then publish a new release of your Dart package and other developer using it can update to this new release without updating their own code.

Comment: _If you have a public field you can change it to a public get/setter pair and store the value in a field with a different name._

Its usage is somewhat difficult to grasp...

Comment: The getter/setter must take the name the field had (replace the field by a getter/setter pair) or replace a final (read-only) by a getter.

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. But, its usage is what I can't understand. Would you recommend me a text related to this subject? I googled for a while but could't find.

Comment: In the above example code, public member 'name' is removed, and private member '_name' is newly inserted. I don't know what is the benefit of this change at all?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Maybe this one http://www.springer.com/computer/book/978-1-4302-6481-1
see https://www.dartlang.org/books/ for more or https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/

Comment: I didn't notice that change. That is exactly what I mentioned in a comment above. Instead of a member `name` you have a getter/setter `name`. Getters/setters are like functions but with a bit different syntax - functions can't store values therefore a private field `_name` was introduced. The code to access `Project.name` doesn't change but the setter introduces additional validation.

Comment: Though the setter introduced additional validation, it does not seem to be a main focus of removing 'name' and introducing'_name'. I think there must be some key benefit of converting public field to private field using new getter/setter. I want to know is what that KEY benefit is...

Comment: The main purpose is that you can add additional logic (validation) without breaking users code. You can't do validation on a field. The benefit is that when you start building an application you don't need to care if you might need some additional logic sometimes later. Just use a field (start simple) and change it later when the requirement comes up. Without this you had to know beforehand if this requirement is likely to come up or to be on the safe side always use getters/setters to have the option to add code later without breaking other peoples (or your own) code.

Comment: I may need some more reading and exercise to understand the benefits of converting existing public members to new private members with new getter/setters.

Comment: I know of adding additional logic. but, isn't it easy to keep existing public members and to change existing getter/setter without breaking other people/my codes?

Comment: Of course you can change existing getters/setters without breaking changes. The point is - when you start with a field and the requirement comes up that something should happen when the field is updated, the best solution is to convert the field to a getter/setter.

Comment: I see. It's the point _the best solution is to convert the field to a getter/setter_ 
It may needs some time to fully understand the phrase.
Thank you again Gunter.

Comment: It's just about knowing in advance if you might later on need some additional logic when a field is updated. Future-prediction is not a strength of humans and always using getters/setters just to be on the safe side is cumbersome. It's a very simple thing but fields are very common so this can safe a little bit of work but very often.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the OP's confusion, but here goes: the reason you need to introduce the "_name" private member is because a getter/setter pair replaces (not enhances) the "name" public member.  You can't have a public member and a getter/setter pair with the same name.  So what was a public member called "name" before, is now a getter/setter pair called "name" (more specifically "set name()" and "get name").  But the value still needs to be stored somewhere, so you introduce a new, private member called "_name", and the getter/setter pair gets and sets that, new, private member.